# Why my list only updates when refresh

Tags: angularjs

I dont know why my list doesn;t update when I click `add` . It only updates when I refresh. Here is my code

**services**

```
function getCustomer() {
        return $http.get(API_URL+'api/customer')
                     .then(getCustomerSuccess)
                     .catch(function(err) {

                             });
                function getCustomerSuccess(response) {

                    return response.data;
                    }
                    }
```

Js

```
function getCustomer() {
                        dataServices.getCustomer()
                                 .then(function(response){
                    vm.customer = response;
})
                }

                vm.add = function(customer) {
                    dataServices.addCustomer(customer);
                    getCustomer();
                    logger.success('Add Customer Success');
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why my list only updates when refresh

The problem is: you resolve Promise inside Service and return object instead Promise.  After refresh, you trigger digest cycle that takes new data you loaded from server

From your code, a.e. `dataServices.getCustomer().then(/* .. */)` you expect Promise

Use [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q):

> A service that helps you run functions asynchronously, and use their
>   return values (or exceptions) when they are done processing.

```
function getCustomerSuccess(response) {
   var deferred = $q.defer();              
   deferred.resolve(response.data);               
   return deferred.promise;       
 }
```

Comment: Thank for suggest I will try it . But can you explain for me why should use $q in this case

Comment: It's not work too . I'm try test with diferrent file and it work . But In my file , It's not work . I'm use CORS , so CORS is related to this or not ?